# Can I make IPython notebook from PythonTeX ?

Tags: code, python

Let's example like this :

```
\begin{ipythonconsole}
1+1 
\end{ipythonconsole}
```

then I will get the result like this :

```
In[1]  : 1+1 
Out[1] : 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate questions here.

1. **Can a document using PythonTeX be converted into an IPython notebook, which is the interactive, web-based notebook format provided by IPython?** The answer is no. PythonTeX provides formatting and inline commands that currently have no direct equivalent in the IPython notebook, so a one-to-one conversion is impossible.  It would be possible, at least in principle, to do a round-trip conversion with a limited subset of PythonTeX.  I may look into that possibility at some point, but I currently have no plans to try to implement it myself.
2. **Can PythonTeX's `pyconsole` environment (or an equivalent) use IPython instead of plain Python?** Not currently, but adding support would probably be relatively simple. The `pyconsole` environment uses [Python's `code` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html) to emulate an interactive interpreter. Adding support for IPython would involve using IPython's equivalent of the `code` module. I am not familiar with the IPython internals, but if you or someone else wants to track down the comparable IPython functions, then I would be happy to try to add IPython console support.

Comment: Thank for your quick answer , but I don't enough know about IPython console, and I only use it :)